# Returning boolean in php based on login form

Tags: php, authentication, boolean

I am trying to use php to verify user login information. User information is held in a text file in the format name:password. My code returns true if the last name in the text file matches the passed name and password. However, if a name and password combo is passed that is contained in the middle of the text file the code returns false. I am new to php, java is my main language.

```
    <?php
    $users = file("users.txt");
    #this line is just here for testing reasons
    echo check_user("isabel", "washington12", $users);

    function check_user($name, $password, $users) {
        $users_size = count($users);
        for($i = 0; $i < $users_size; $i++) {
            $curr_user = explode(":", $users[$i]);
            if($curr_user[0] == $name && $curr_user[1] == $password) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FAlSE;
    }
?>
```

**sample text file**

```
bob:firework
krista:blueheart
jason:hatcap
isabel:washington12
andrew:chalkboard
```

Comment: saving raw passwords in a text file on your server is something you shouldn't do!!!! people will be able to access the file and get everyones login information!!!

Comment: That's not entirely true. It can be hidden away through `.htaccess` @NoLiver92 However it is not a good idea, it can work; I used it before. Using a DB is much better.

Comment: I know. This is all dummy data. I am not even going to publish this site. I am just learning php. I do not plan to publish anything until I learn mySQL and read up on web security.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in your file has a newline char at the end of it. `file` does not strip newline chars by default. You must `trim` the data you are comparing to:

```
<?php
$users = file("users.txt");
    #this line is just here for testing reasons
    echo check_user("isabel", "washington12", $users);

    function check_user($name, $password, $users) {
        $users_size = count($users);
        for($i = 0; $i < $users_size; $i++) {
            $curr_user = explode(":", $users[$i]);
            if(trim($curr_user[0]) == $name && trim($curr_user[1]) == $password) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

?>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag with `file` instead of using `trim`

`$users = file("users.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, you could just use:

```
$valid = (rtrim($curr_user[0]) == trim($name)) && (rtrim($curr_user[1]) == trim($password));
return $valid;
```

Do you have the code to open the file and use the file handle to read through it line by line?   You can find examples of that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).